# Nest nodes in XML generated from SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to generate an XML file which looks like following.

```
<products>
   <product>
     <sku>12345</sku>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
              <name>AttributeName</name>
              <row>
              <name>ProdName</name>
              <value>someProduct</value>
              </row>
            </attribute>

            <attribute>
              <name>AttributeName</name>
              <row>
              <name>color</name>
              <value>Blue</value>
              </row>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </product>
</products>
```

With following SQL query I could generate something very close but need to fine tune it.

```
bcp "SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(sku)) as sku, 
(SELECT 'AttributeName' AS [name],'ProdName' AS [row/name],ProdName AS [row/value] FOR XML PATH ('attribute'), Type),
(SELECT 'AttributeName' AS [name],'color' AS [row/name], color AS [row/value]      FOR XML PATH ('attribute'), Type)  
FROM Tbl_Product WHERE (SKU = 12345) FOR XML PATH ('product'), ROOT('products'),Type" queryout "..\Desktop\sample.xml" -c -T

<products>
   <product>
     <sku>12345</sku>
        <!-- need   <attributes> here -->          
            <attribute>
              <name>AttributeName</name>
              <row>
              <name>ProdName</name>
              <value>someProduct</value>
              </row>
            </attribute>

            <attribute>
              <name>AttributeName</name>
              <row>
              <name>color</name>
              <value>Blue</value>
              </row>
            </attribute>
     <!-- end <attributes>  here-->  
    </product>
</products>
```

Is there a way to nest all `<attribute>` nodes inside `<attributes>`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of String concatenation (+) in SQL. It took me over a week to figure that one little thing out. Here's what solved my problem. Might help someone else in future.

```
bcp "SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(sku)) as sku, (SELECT 'AttributeName' AS [attribute/name],
'ProdName' AS [attribute/row/name], 
ProdName AS [attribute/row/value],
+'',  
'AttributeName' AS [attribute/name],
'color' AS [attribute/row/name], 
color AS [attribute/row/value]    
FROM Tbl_Product Where (SKU = TP.SKU) 
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('attributes'), Type)  

FROM Tbl_Product TP WHERE (SKU = 12345) 
FOR XML PATH ('product'), ROOT('products'),Type"   queryout "..\Desktop\sample.xml" -c -T
```